# Showing that if $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are independent r.v.'s with a particular distribution, their average converges almost surely to $-1$?

Tags: probability

I have that $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are independent random variables such that $X_n = n^2-1$ with probability $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and that $X_n = -1$ with probability $1-\frac{1}{n^2}$. If I define the sum to be $S_n = X_1+\ldots+X_n$, I would like to show that $\frac{S_n}{n} \to -1$ almost surely. My approach here is to use the Borel-Cantelli theorem. Ultimately, I would like to show that $P(\frac{S_n}{n} \to -1) =1$. To do this, it instantly implies by intuition and by backtracing that I would like the sum $\sum_n P(X_n \neq -1)$ to be convergent to some real number. However, I cannot fully understand why this is or how I can get such a sum. Am I missing something here? thanks!

Comment: $P(X_i=-1\text { eventually})=1$ by Borel-Cantelli which implies $S_n/n\to -1$.

Comment: @A.S. I can see how it intuitively implies that $\frac{S_n}{n}\to -1$, as it means that for large enough $n$, it will be $-1$ from that point forward, but how can I show this fact formally?

Comment: $S_n/n=S_k/n+\frac {S_n-S_k}{n-k}\frac{n-k}n$ where $S_k$ has all the not $-1$. The first summand goes to zero and  the second to $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $S_n/n \to -1$ if $X_n = -1$ eventually. What are the chances this doesn't happen? The negation of $X_n = -1$ eventually is $X_n \neq -1$ infinitely often. Let's show this happens with zero probability. By Borel Cantelli, it suffices to show $\sum_n P(X_n \neq -1) < \infty$. Of course $\sum_n P(X_n \neq -1) = \sum_n \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$ so we are in business. Note we do not need independence for this proof.